# iframe/embed salesforce into another site

Tags: iframe, cors, clickjacking

Is this possible to do anymore?
I'm trying to iframe Salesforce, in it's entirety for SSO functionality without having the user leave my web application. My application is a connected app and we would be working with the admins of any clients directly to setup for this, so there is not a concern of access rights or configuration. If salesforce allows it we would be able to also configure specific domains.

I've tried configuring CSP Trusted Sites & Remote Site Settings.

I've looked into 'clickjack' protection but that seems to be inside of sites and communities which is a subset of the experience. I'm looking for the full experience as though it were opened in a new tab, but in an iframe.

Currently the error I'm getting is:

```
Refused to frame 'https://cs195.lightning.force.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".
```

note: when I open in a new tab instead of an iframe the SSO functionality works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't iframe/embed Salesforce in an app. You'd want to use an OAuth flow with a state parameter to navigate the user back to the previous state in your web app. See the [Web Server Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5) documentation for details.