# Is it possible and how to login to a SF Org that was opened in an iFrame?

Tags: iframe, browser, grant-login-access

Our web application needs to open a Salesforce Org application in an iFrame.
Any ideas if that is possible and what would you recommend to read in order to achieve that?

I know that Lightning out(LO) has been designed to be used in iFrames, but is it possible to use LO to login to SF and then redirect to another, page that uses LO again?  (or even LWC ?)
Or any other ways to achieve opening SF Org application in an iFrame in the web browser!?

**Use case details:**

Our SF application is an adapter between SF and other web/desktop applications. Our base functionality includes FDC3 or similar interoperability messages between SF and the other web/desktop applications. So, our best option would be the ability to view SObject records and also execute CRUD operations on SObjects configure SF.

Comment: Without the underlying reason, we can't really give a specific answer. This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please [edit] your question to describe why you feel you need this solution, so we can better help you understand if this a correct solution or to identify an alternative.

Comment: See also [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/353328/2984), which may or may not be relevant

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox for the request and the follow up. I saw your [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/330145/iframe-embed-salesforce-into-another-site?rq=1) and I was thinking is it possible to use redirections to achieve that somehow? My Site redirects to SSO of SF, then after success in SSO I'm redirected back to my site with a SF page with the our custom application? I also updated the question description with the use case.

Comment: You can't do this inside Salesforce., but this may work in a Digital Experience.

Comment: As per The Fox's last comment, you definitely cannot iframe a standard Salesforce UI into an external site. This is disallowed for security reasons and it cannot be disabled. You can iframe in Digital Experience pages if you set the required configuration on the digital experience itself.

Comment: I see, it seems reasonable that in DE to be able to achieve. thanks Phil and Fox!